# How can i manage controller methods as per user role in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, roles, middleware

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('roles:Author')->only(['index','show','create']);
    $this->middleware('roles:User')->only(['index','show']);
}
```

In my controller i want access methods as per users role for e.g if user role is admin then he has to access all methods of controller, if user role is Author then he has access of index,create and show method and if role is User then he has only access of index and show method.

Comment: Check laravel document : http://www.laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Comment: Do you use a package for role management?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova no i create pivot table for user role and checking role in model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at `Gates` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#gates)).

In your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` add:

```
Gate::define('create-post', function ($user) {
    return $user->isAuthor(); //Here you should check the users role
});
```

And then in your controller's method `create()`:

```
if (Gate::allows('create-post')) {
    // The current user can create posts...
}
```

The other two methods: `index()` and `show()` are available to both roles so there's no action required.

Comment: thanks for teaching new but i have to add this condition in each method of controller, and i want like manage from constructor so you have any idea which manage controller from constructor.